# passing variable from controller to view page shows undefined variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've passed a variable `temp` from controller to view page. 
While debugging the search method, I am getting data from database to the variable temp. 
When I pass this variable to view page, it is showing error as

```
 ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Undefined variable: temp (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\lsapp\resources\views\pages\MySearch.blade.php)
```

I doubt the error is most likely due to `route` configuration but I am not sure. There might be other errors too. But the process of passing variable from controller to view page is same, but also I am getting the error.

controller code block

```
public function searchDev()
    {
        return view ( 'pages.MySearch');
    }
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $UserName = $request->input('MyName');

    if($UserName != ""){
        $temp = temp::where ( 'NAME', 'LIKE', '%' . $UserName . '%' )->get (['id','NAME','CONTACT','TEMP_ADDRESS']);
        if (count ( $temp ) > 0)
        {
            /*
                getting result from database
                dump($temp);                 
                return response()->json($temp);
                 */
            return view('pages.MySearch', [
                'temp' => $temp
            ]);
        }                
        else
        {
            return view ( 'pages.MySearch')->with('alert-danger', 'Sorry No details found');
        }

    }
}
```

view page code block

```
@foreach($temp as $data)
 <tr>
      <td> {{$data['NAME']}} </td>
     <td> {{$data['CONTACT']}} </td>
     <td> {{$data['TEMP_ADDRESS']}} </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

route code

```
Route::get('/MySearch','MyController@searchDev');
Route::post('/MySearch','MyController@search');
```

The error is general, but I can't debug the error what is the cause of the error. Please help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are not always passing temp variable to view, you must check that whether the variable exists or not before using it in your blade view.
Check that whether the $temp variable exists before using it anywhere in blade

```
@if(isset($temp))
@foreach($temp as $data)
 <tr> 
       <td> {{$data['NAME']}} </td>
       <td> {{$data['CONTACT']}} </td> 
       <td> {{$data['TEMP_ADDRESS']}} </td> 
</tr>
@endforeach
@endif
```

Or alternatively, you should check at the start of blade view that a variable exists or assign assign it some default value so the page won't break.

```
@php
$temp = isset($temp) ? $temp : [];
@endphp
```

Comment: Thank it solved my problem. I want to know, what this code block do `@if(isset($temp))`, keeping this `if` my problem was solved. Please reply. Thank You!!!

Comment: this condition will be true, if the $temp vaiable is set and it is not null. You @foreach loop will be excuted only if $temp exists. You can find further details here.
[link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 2):

In your else section you are not passing any variable

So use this instead

```
return view ( 'pages.MySearch', compact('temp'))->with('alert-danger', 'Sorry No details found');
```

for blade:

```html
 @foreach($temp as $data)
 <tr>
      <td> {{$data->name}} </td>
     <td> {{$data->CONTACT}} </td>
     <td> {{$data->TEMP_ADDRESS}} </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```